# Log to filesystem from multiple classes

Tags: java, logging, io, java.util.logging

I am using the build in `java.util.logging.Logger` to log some information during runtime. Also I'd like the logs to be written on the filesystem. So basically I thought I would create the Logger with a `Singleton Pattern`, use it in all my classes and just save the file to the filesystem. Unfortunately no file is ever written. I see the logs in my console output and all the logs from all the multiple classes are displaying there just fine. But i am not sure why my code won't create a file.

Here is what I've tried:

```
package util;

import gui.ExceptionDialog;
import org.codehaus.plexus.util.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;


    public class LoggerWrapper {

    public static final Logger myLogger = Logger.getLogger("Stockparty Log");

    private static LoggerWrapper instance = null;
    private static Date date = new Date();
    private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    private static String fileName = "spLog-"+formatter.format(date)+".log";

    public static LoggerWrapper getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            prepareLogger(Level.INFO);
            instance = new LoggerWrapper ();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    private static void prepareLogger(Level level) {

        File file = null;
        if (OSValidator.isWindows()) {
            System.out.println("This is Windows");
            file = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + File.separator + "StockParty" + File.separator + fileName);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.forceMkdir(file.getParentFile());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ExceptionDialog exceptionDialog = new ExceptionDialog("Schreibfehler", "Ordnder, um Statistik abzulegen konnte nicht erzeugt werden", ex);
                    exceptionDialog.show();
                }
            }

        } else if (OSValidator.isMac()) {
            System.out.println("This is Mac");

            file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Library" + File.separator + "Application Support"
                    + File.separator + "StockParty" + File.separator + fileName);
            if (!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.forceMkdir(file.getParentFile());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ExceptionDialog exceptionDialog = new ExceptionDialog("Schreibfehler", "Ordnder, um Statistik abzulegen konnte nicht erzeugt werden", ex);
                    exceptionDialog.show();
                }
            }

            FileHandler myFileHandler = null;
            try {
                myFileHandler = new FileHandler(file.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myFileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            myLogger.addHandler(myFileHandler);
            myLogger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
            myLogger.setLevel(level);
        }
    }

}
```

Oh and by the way the directory in `APPDATA` is created only the file is missing.

Comment: do you have permission to create files on particular location?

Comment: Check whether the path that you get from System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Library" + File.separator + "Application Support" exist?

Comment: I am on windows so the path for mac won't exist but is never used also. The path is correct for windows i checked it. It looks like your first assumption is right. My created Directory "StockParty" i n AppData is write-protected. I will verify that this is the bug i was searching for and report my results right here. Thanks for this idea

Comment: But if this really is the bug i was searching for why is the directory created but not the file and also shouldn't i catch a IOException in this case ?

Comment: Check the parehenteses nesting. After a first reading, I'm afraid the addHandler method is only invoked when OSValidator.isMac()==true.

Comment: Thank you very much that was it. I didn't saw that one.